# How to check if a given user is a member of the built-in Administrators group?

Tags: .net, security

I need to check programmatically (in .NET) whether a given user (domain account) is a member of the built-in Administrators group on a current computer (the one where the application gets executed).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about .Net, but in win32, the easy way is to call IsUserAnAdmin(). If you need more control, you can open the process token and check with CheckTokenMembership for each group you need to check

**Edit:** See [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/CheckTokenMembership.html) for .NET sample code (Thanks chopeen)

Answer (score 2):

There is a Win32 API for this you could P/Invoke: [IsUserAnAdmin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776463(VS.85).aspx)

The question is more complex on Vista ... see this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/cjacks/archive/2006/10/09/How-to-Determine-if-a-User-is-a-Member-of-the-Administrators-Group-with-UAC-Enabled-on-Windows-Vista.aspx).

Comment: "IsUserAnAdmin function is a wrapper for CheckTokenMembership. It is recommended to call that function directly to determine Administrator group status rather than calling IsUserAnAdmin". (From the linked page)

Comment: I hadn't noticed the warning before.  I wonder why Microsoft would consider deprecating such a simpler helper ... fortunately they have a good track record for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop the groups like i did in this answer:

[Determining members of local groups via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437/determining-members-of-local-groups-via-c#45458)

After reading some more, the easiest thing would be to use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace. Here is how it can be used:

http://www.leastprivilege.com/SystemDirectoryServicesAccountManagement.aspx

Sample:

```
public static bool IsUserInGroup(string username, string groupname, ContextType type)
{
    PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(type);

    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
        context,
        IdentityType.SamAccountName,
        username);
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
        context, groupname);

    return user.IsMemberOf(group);
}
```

Comment: The System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace is new to .NET 3.5, isn't it?

Comment: First sentence in the linked article:
"Looking through some of the new 3.5 stuff I stumbled over a new assembly named "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" - that caught my attention."

Comment: Sorry, I missed it.

Could you add information CheckTokenMembership to your answer to make it complete (so I can mark it as accepted answer)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the currently running user then

```
using System.Security.Principal;

WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal wp = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);

if (wp.IsInRole("BUILTIN\Administrators"))
   // Is Administrator
else
   // Is Not
```

If not then I expect its possible to set **identity** to a particular user but not looked into how.