# How to fix the high usage of WmiPrvse.exe when it searches for the files through WMI

Tags: c#, process, wmi, cpu-usage, taskmanager

When I pass this below link query I find that the CPU usage goes till 100%

[Query for searching the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604027/how-to-find-list-of-file-path-in-files-and-in-sub-folders-of-c-drive-based-on-di)

How Could I minimize this usage ,because if other application simultaneously runs it may cause harm to those application .I saw WMIPrvSE.exe is consuming CPU's  100 % memory.I can neither exit this application because it is fetching the data through WMI. 
I do search other system queries from the WMI having different object for management object searcher as given in this link

[Query for finding users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778562/how-to-check-if-every-users-on-the-system-has-administrator-rights-in-c-sharp).

When I completely execute the whole program ,I find it that  CPU usage goes entirely up to 100% and doesn't come down till the application fetches all the data.

While debugging the code the usage goes down but trying to put `Thread.Sleep` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you using an old, single-core CPU?

Comment: Yes ...When i check on the other system with same cpu processor I dont find this exe @kennyzx

Comment: Well i mean, if you have a modern CPU with more than one core, the CPU usage can't go to 100%. On my machine, running the code from the link, the CPU usage is well below 50%.

Comment: did u find any thing related with WMIPrvSE.exe @kennyzx

Comment: well in that code it just fetches one type of extension ,i need to find around 6-10 extension types @kennyzx

Comment: yes, it uses 25% of CPU. Maybe it is because my CPU has four cores, so the code fully occupies one of the cores, the other three is idle. But on your machine, since (I guess) the CPU has only one core, so the CPU usage is 100%.

Comment: @kennyzx :How could we minimize this usage???