# Remove user account

Tags: c#, wmi

How can I remove user local account of administrators group with the help of WMI in C#. (NOT using `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`).

I have tried this code. but I don't know how to run it.

```
  using (var myDeleteUser = new StreamWriter("DeleteUser.vbs"))
        {
            myDeleteUser.WriteLine("Set objAdminGroup = GetObject(\"WinNT://" + hostHame + "/" + Settings.AdministratorsGroup + ",group\")");
           myDeleteUser.WriteLine("Set objUser = GetObject(\"WinNT://" + domain + "/" + userName + ",user\")");
            myDeleteUser.WriteLine("objAdminGroup.Remove(objUser.ADsPath)");
        }
```

EDIT:
I try to do this:

```
 Process proc = new Process();
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = "DeleteUser.vbs";
 proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 proc.Start();
 proc.WaitForExit();
 int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
 proc.Close();
```

But I have an error(vbs permission denied Getobject) in VBS file.

Comment: All this is doing is writing a 3 line VBScript file. Why would you do this? Just create the VBS yourself and run it.

Answer (score 0):

You want the Win32_UserAccount 
Note the c# code implementation here - the delete on top of should be trivial

[Enumerate Windows user group members on remote system using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514/enumerate-windows-user-group-members-on-remote-system-using-c-sharp)

Are you looking at deleting the account, or just remove from that group?
If you want to remove from the group check out the Win32_GroupUser object.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx